# The optimization problem of the equal risk contribution portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk-parity

I try to understand the equal risk contribution (ERC) portfolio as described in [On the Properties of Equally-Weighted Risk Contributions Portfolios](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45397778_On_the_Properties_of_Equally-Weighted_Risk_Contributions_Portfolios?enrichId=rgreq-e57c2f5c85f2f372662ff322fd9faf92-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzQ1Mzk3Nzc4O0FTOjY4NDE3NDY5MjMxOTIzNEAxNTQwMTMxMzY2NzEz&el=1_x_2&_esc=publicationCoverPdf) by Teiletche and Roncalli.
For a given covariance matrix of $n$ assets $\Sigma$ they define the following optimization problem (the $y$-problem):
$$
y^* = \text{arg min} \{ \sqrt{ y^T \Sigma y}\}
$$
with the constraints
$$
y \ge 0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i \ge c.
$$
Where in the above $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

What I assume:

- $c$ of course needs to be greater than $- \infty$, otherwise we would have the minimum volatlity portfolio.
- For $c = -n \ln n$ we arrive at the equal weighted portfolio (all weights equal to $1/n$).

Is the following understanding correct?

- If I first pick some $c \in (-\infty,   -n \ln n)$, then I can solve the above problem whith the solution $y^*(c)$.
- Then I can rescale the solution: $x_i^* = \frac{y^*_i(c)}{\sum_{i=1}^n y^*_i(c)}$ to get $x^* = (x^*_i)_{i=1}^n $ which are the weights of the ERC.

Thus, if they speak of an arbitrary $c$, they mean that this $c$ needs to be chosen from a certain interval. Then I get a solution for $y^*$ and after rescaling the particular choice of $c$ vanishes. Is this correct?

In the article above they also write that the solution can be derived directly by setting
$c^* = c - n \ln \{\sum_{i=1}^n y^*_i(c)\}$, where $c$ was used to find $y*(c)$ and then solving (the $x$-problem)
$$
x^* = \text{arg min} \{ \sqrt{ x^T \Sigma x}\}
$$
with the constraints
$$
x \ge 0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i \ge c^* \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1.
$$

I tried to wrap my head around this for a while. In my view the choice of $c$ is not that arbitrary. If somebody has thought about this optimization problem, then I would be happy to hear your comments. Thank you!

EDIT:
I have programmed the above in R. You can find the code and an explanatory html file [on github](https://github.com/rwarnung/ERC) or the [html file directly](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rwarnung/ERC/blob/master/ERC_optim.html).
My interpretation seems to be right. Just choose $c$ and then rescale to have the sum of weights equal to one. I would like to understand this deeper. Thus please join the discussion if you like.

EDIT2:
I started to understand the inequality constraint better. I assume that for the same reason as for the $y$-problem we get that the logarithmic constraint of the $x$-problem is actually reached:
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i = c^*.
$$
Then we can insert $c^{\ast} = c - n \ln( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\ast})$ and thus
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i = c - n \ln( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\ast}).
$$
$y^{\ast}$ is the optimal solution of the $y$-problem with the logarithmic constraint using $c$. Thus it must hold that $\sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i^{\ast} = c$, and we get

$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i^{\ast} - n \ln( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\ast}),
$$
which can be re-written to
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left(\frac{y_i^{\ast}}{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\ast}} \right).
$$
But this does not imply that $x_i = \frac{y_i^{\ast}}{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{\ast}}$ which would mean that $x$ is the re-scaled optimum of the $y$-problem. Furthermore, in my reasoning, the objective functon pretty much loses its meaning.

Finally, I am stuck. Do you have any idea why the special choice of the constraint immediately gives the ERC?

Comment: Nice question, +1. They explain the reasoning in the [appendix A2 of the paper (p. 21)](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/download/erc.pdf). If I understand correctly, the FOC of this problem, evaluated at the optimal point, yields that the contribution of each risk equals some $\lambda_c$. HTH

Comment: @Kermittfrog thank you for your comment. I agree that considering the Lagrangian, the constraint with $c$ leads to the equation where each risk contributions equals the Langrange multiplier $\lambda_c$. I am not good at ootimization theory, but if we could add the constraint $\sum y_i = 1$, then we would get the ERC portfolio directly. Why do we leave this constraint out?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I started a bounty ... I added some more context. Maybe you want to discuss more :)

Comment: Are we sure that $c$ must be chosen $< -n \ln(n)$ in the y-problem? What is the reason? When I try with an arbitrary $c=1$ it seems to work in all the cases I tried. (Cases do not prove anything, I know).

Comment: @nbbo2 That is correct, the boundary only holds for the $x$-problem with the sum constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the following: The optimization problem with the equality constraint
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^*(c) &= \text{argmin} \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} \\
\textrm{s.t.} & \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i \geq c \\
              & 1^Tx =1 \\
              & x \geq0
\end{aligned}
$$
has the following Lagrange function:
$$
f(x;\lambda_0,\lambda,\lambda_c)=\sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} - \lambda_0(1^Tx-1)-\lambda^Tx-\lambda_c\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ln x_i-c\right).
$$
At the optimum
$$
x_i\frac{\partial\sigma(x)}{\partial x_i}=\lambda_0x_i+\lambda_c
$$
holds. But since $\lambda_0=0$ does not have to hold, the resulting portfolio at the optimum would not be an ERC portfolio, which is what you empirically observed in the R notebook. The only value at which $\lambda_0=0$ holds is at $c=c^*$ as the equality constraint is then already fulfilled by virtue of the way in which $c$ is set and the corresponding Lagrange multiplier is thus 0.

[1] *Introduction to Risk Parity and Budgeting*, Thierry Roncalli

Comment: Thank you, this solves it! :)

Comment: Thanks, I coded this algorithm a while ago but now I finally understand **why** it works.