# Risk Budgeting with negative covariance

Tags: portfolio-optimization

Let's say I want to optimise allocations between strategies in a multi-strategy fund.

There are 3 strategies, and the CIO want me to solve the portfolio that has 50% of risk in 1st strategy, 40% in second, and 10% in third.  This is the standard Roncalli stuff (average risk contributions).

This seems to work for a certain range of covariances. But if the third strategy is sufficiently negatively correlated with the first two, a solution is not possible.

How do you deal with this? Presently, I just simply scale all three strategies to have equal volatility on a standalone basis, and then apply the 50/40/10 allocation weights instead of risk weights. But this does not feel quite right.

Comment: What method are you using to find the Roncalli solution? (I believe one of the methods proposed early on in the literature, the one that minimizes sum of squares of deviations, does not always work). The method described here always works AFAIK https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/71152/the-optimization-problem-of-the-equal-risk-contribution-portfolio

Comment: I doubt the method is the issue. The solution might just not exist, as explained above. What do we do in practice when this happens? A strategy is negatively correlated so it is very valiable. But it's MRC is also -ve (it's reducing portfolio vol).

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in your case? Division by zero, infinite loop, taking the square root of a negative number, inconsistent equations, etc. that causes the solution to not exist.  Can you give an example of a 3 x 3 covariance which causes the problem.